# The value of the function with a very small Imaginary part but can be Plotted

Tags: complex, precision-and-accuracy

I have a function `Y[x_,β2_]`, It can be plotted normally. But when I take specific values,  I get something like `+0.000000*I` when x is equal to some value, but it should't be able to `Plot` the function if it has complex numbers when I don't take the absolute value.

I've seen some answers that say `Chop` can be used, but the function `Y[x_,β2_]` can be drawn normally so it must don't have a imaginary part. The reason I think this imaginary part has a definite value is because the running result of my other code changes when I use `Chop[Y[x_,β2_]]` in a `Piecewise` Function. And I think this problem is probably the cause of my other code running wrong. One result of a certain value:

> 483.282589+0.000000 I

Here is the code about `Y[x_,β2_]`, for different `Q1, Q2` has different `Y[x_,β2_]`, just one of which is listed below. When I use Chop or not Chop it Plot the same result, but when I run other functions with `Y[x_,β2_]` (as discussed below), adding Chop gets a completely different result. :

```
Clear["Global`*"]
Print["Q1 = ", DecimalForm[q1 = 122500. - 517.194735, {20, 6}]];

Print["Q2 = ", DecimalForm[q2 = 114200., {20, 6}]];
Print["A24 = ", 
  DecimalForm[
   A24 = 97.001875 (122500. - 517.194735)/122500., {20, 6}]];
δ = -1.2131226805013586 10^-6;
Axr = -1/9 (q1^2 - q1 q2 + q2^2);
Bxr[x_] := -(q1 - q2)/(4 δ) x^2 + 
   1/54 (q1 + q2) (9 q1 q2 - 2 (q1 + q2)^2);

β[x_, bxr_] := ArcCos[bxr[x]/(-Axr)^(3/2)];
Y[x_, β2_] := 
  2 Sqrt[-Axr] Cos[β2[x, Bxr]/3] - 1/3 (q1 + q2);
Xd0 = 2 (-δ/(q1 - q2))^(1/2) (Bxr[0] + (-Axr)^(3/2))^(1/2);
DecimalForm[Y[A24/2, β], {12, 6}]
Plot[-Y[x, β], {x, -Xd0, Xd0}]
```

I need to define a piecewise function usinig `Y[x_,β2_]` and use `Array` turn that piecewise function into an Array `Lensarray`, then `plot` the `Lensarray`. The `Lensarray`drawing code is as follows, It reminds me that `Less::nord: tried to use 37344.8-3240.47i for an invalid comparison.`. Then I want to use `Lensarray` to do an iterative calculation. And then the iteration went wrong too. when I iterate with the matrix `LensArray`, it gets an error saying `Is not a non-empty list, nor is it a rectangular array of numeric quantities`, and when I check the stack trace , I find that it's due to the piecewise function. It shows that the array contains piecewise functions. So I think there's something wrong with 'Lensarray' or 'Lens'. But I check the matrix `Lensarray`, but it's really made up of numbers, there's no piecewise function. So why did this happen?

```
δ = 1.2131226805013586 10^-6;
β = 4.75349804 10^-8;
χ = -2 δ + 2 I β;
δ1 = -1.2131226805013586 10^-6;
δ2 = (1.2131226805013586 10^-6)/(1 - 1.2131226805013586 10^-6);
f = 5151736.70155;
LensLength = Yrange[[62]];

Table[Subscript[Axr, 
   i] = ((-1)/9) (q1[[i]]^2 - q1[[i]] q2[[i]] + q2[[i]]^2), {i, 1, 
   62}];
Table[Subscript[Bxr, i] = 
   Module[{δs}, δs = 
     If[OddQ[i], δ1, δ2]; ((-(q1[[i]] - 
            q2[[i]]))/(4δs)) x^2 + (1/54) (q1[[i]] + 
        q2[[i]]) (9 q1 [[i]] q2[[i]] - 2 (q1[[i]] + q2[[i]])^2)], {i, 
   1, 62}];
Table[Subscript[β, i] = 
   ArcCos[Subscript[Bxr, i]/(-Subscript[Axr, i])^((3/2))], {i, 1, 62}];
Table[Subscript[Y, i] = 
   Abs[-(2 Sqrt[-Subscript[Axr, i]] Cos[
         Subscript[β, i]/3] - (1/3) (q1[[i]] + q2[[i]]))], {i, 
   1, 62}];
Len1 = {χ, 
   0 <= y < (Sqrt[x^2 + f^2] - f)/δ + 10 && 
    0 < y < Yrange[[1]] && -50 <= x <= 50};

Lens[x_, y_] = 
  Piecewise[
   Join[{Len1}, 
    Table[{χ, 
      Subscript[Y, i] + Apcie[[i]] <= y < 
        Subscript[Y, i + 1] + Apcie[[i + 1]] && 
       Yrange[[i]] <= y < Yrange[[i + 1]] && -50 <= x <= 50}, {i, 1, 
      61, 2}]]];

Lensarray = Array[Lens, {Nx, Nz}, {{xStart, xEnd}, {0, Maxz}}];
LenF = Lensarray;
MatrixPlot[Abs[Lensarray], ColorFunction -> "Monochrome", 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic]
AbsoluteTime[] - time
```

Here is the definition of the matrix used in the function:

```
q1={5151536.701550,2499990.000000,1614774.131776,1169990.000000,904742.171199,729990.000000,605711.526739,513990.000000,443182.277830,387990.000000,343258.780795,306590.000000,275934.940760,249990.000000,227506.115311,208190.000000,191077.508363,176290.000000,162848.416323,151190.000000,140369.167291,130990.000000,121982.805265,114190.000000,106694.176102,100290.000000,93923.837408,88490.000000,82991.123566,78390.000000,73613.061532,69670.000000,65476.568200,62140.000000,58472.599719,55590.000000,52312.925767,49820.000000,46892.253210,44720.000000,42084.946419,40180.000000,37775.450513,36102.000000,33901.020142,32420.000000,30386.185769,29060.000000,27166.524869,25970.000000,24198.228993,23120.000000,21453.974356,20470.000000,18886.440141,17985.000000,16481.195581,15650.000000,14213.422727,13445.000000,12071.827247,11355.000000};

q2={2500000.00,1615000.00,1170000.00,905000.00,730000.00,606000.00,514000.00,443500.00,388000.00,343600.00,306600.00,276300.00,250000.00,227900.00,208200.00,191500.00,176300.00,163300.00,151200.00,140850.00,131000.00,122500.00,114200.00,107240.00,100300.00,94500.00,88500.00,83600.00,78400.00,74250.00,69680.00,66140.00,62150.00,59150.00,55600.00,53010.00,49830.00,47600.00,44730.00,42800.00,40190.00,38500.00,36112.00,34630.00,32430.00,31120.00,29070.00,27905.00,25980.00,24940.00,23130.00,22198.00,20480.00,19637.00,17995.00,17234.00,15660.00,14970.00,13455.00,12830.00,11365.00,10798.00};


Apcie={422.115008,432.115008,900.361323,910.361323,1440.287177,1450.287177,2041.061643,2051.061643,2697.077993,2707.077993,3403.093596,3413.093596,4158.904889,4168.904889,4972.510513,4982.510513,5841.823636,5851.823636,6768.969999,6778.969999,7754.012562,7764.012562,8813.501181,8823.501181,9926.509448,9936.509448,11105.652528,11115.652528,12346.394885,12356.394885,13645.086416,13655.086416,14984.837936,14994.837936,16358.648861,16368.648861,17766.072000,17776.072000,19196.022557,19206.022557,20642.637485,20652.637485,22102.984088,22112.984088,23571.045417,23581.045417,25050.097410,25060.097410,26540.372202,26550.372202,28034.705468,28044.705468,29536.538260,29546.538260,31048.730592,31058.730592,32567.164839,32577.164839,34090.612687,34100.612687,35618.226849,35628.226849};

Yrange={210.000000,657.983232,657.983232,1168.190124,1168.190124,1738.760438,1738.760438,2368.783813,2368.783813,3048.297198,3048.297198,3778.152836,3778.152836,4562.789578,4562.789578,5405.002150,5405.002150,6303.407313,6303.407313,7259.802708,7259.802708,8281.207297,8281.207297,9369.325079,9369.325079,10512.672040,10512.672040,11724.528962,11724.528962,12993.333353,12993.333353,14318.518216,14318.518216,15672.238217,15672.238217,17065.723094,17065.723094,18483.818790,18483.818790,19921.076138,19921.076138,21377.186972,21377.186972,22841.963946,22841.963946,24314.859648,24314.859648,25798.572541,25798.572541,27292.143209,27292.143209,28788.731112,28788.731112,30297.098119,30297.098119,31811.535011,31811.535011,33333.742112,33333.742112,34858.785440,34858.785440,36389.282916};
```

Comment: `Plot` was updated a few years ago to ignore small imaginary parts (as if they were mere round-off errors), so often `Chop` is no longer necessary.  -- The definition of `Xd0` has an extraneous `]`, and I'm not sure if it should be deleted or something else is missing. -- I would ask that a minimal working example not `Print` out things I don't need to see, and there's very little I need to see (thanks).

Comment: @ Michael E2 Sorry I added a superfluous ]. I have corrected it.

Comment: @Michael E2  If I use Chop my function will change dramatically, but logically it should not add Chop because it's a real number, about` Sqrt[-subscript [Axr, I]]` I have calculated it and  It's an array of real numbers . So I really don't understand where the problem is.

Comment: Thanks. I'm a little unclear what you're asking.  The plotting code works the way it should.  The function has a zero `0.` imaginary part that comes from `Cos[β[x, Bxr]/3]`, which basically computes `Cos[ArcCos[t]]`, with `t > 1`.  The code for `Lens` is incomplete (`Apcie` is missing), so I can't see whether it works or not.  What exactly is your question?

Comment: The `Plot` does not change with `Chop`. By "my function," did you mean `Lens[]` or `Y[]` or something else?

Comment: @ Michael E2  I  need the matrix `LensArray` to do an iteration multiple times, But it goes wrong, when I draw  the `LensArray`,  Mathematica tells me: "Try to use 37344.8-3240.4702487609347 I for an invalid comparison."So I think it might be the imaginary part which cause the error.

Comment: @Michael E2 Then when I iterate with the matrix `LensArray`, it gets an error saying there are non-array or quantitative values in the matrix, and when I check the stack trace I find that it' s due to the piecewise function. It shows that the array contains piecewise functions？So I think there's something wrong with 'Lensarray' or 'Lens'。OK, actually the question is complicated, I want to simplify my question, but after the conversation with you, I find it is not easy to simply express where the problem is. I will edit the question again.

Comment: @Michael E2 I always thought the imaginary part was caused by the square root, now I know it came from `Cos[β[x, Bxr]/3]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid imaginary artifacts, either [`Rationalize`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rationalize.html) all input or use [`SetPrecision`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetPrecision.html) so that all calculations are done either exactly or with arbitrary-precision rather than machine precision.

```
Clear["Global`*"]

q1 = 122500. - 517.194735 // Rationalize[#, 0] &;
q2 = 114200; A24 = 
 97.001875 (122500. - 517.194735)/122500 // Rationalize[#, 0] &;
δ = -1.2131226805013586 10^-6 // Rationalize[#, 0] &;
Axr = -1/9 (q1^2 - q1 q2 + q2^2);

Bxr[x_] := -(q1 - q2)/(4 δ) x^2 + 
   1/54 (q1 + q2) (9 q1 q2 - 2 (q1 + q2)^2);

β[x_, bxr_] := ArcCos[bxr[x]/(-Axr)^(3/2)];

Y[x_, β2_] := 
  2 Sqrt[-Axr] Cos[β2[x, Bxr]/3] - 1/3 (q1 + q2) // Simplify;

Xd0 = 2 (-δ/(q1 - q2))^(1/2) (Bxr[0] + (-Axr)^(3/2))^(1/2) // Simplify;

ex = Y[A24/2, β] // Simplify;
```

`-Y[x, β]` is real

```
Simplify[Im[-Y[#, β]] & /@ Range[-Xd0, Xd0, Xd0/10]]

(* {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0} *)
```

However, if evaluated with machine precision there is an imaginary artifact.

```
-Y[#, β] & /@ N[Range[-Xd0, Xd0, Xd0/10]]

(* {-13967.8 + 0. I, -11711.1 + 0. I, -9566.98 + 0. I, -7560.71 + 
  0. I, -5721.25 + 0. I, -4080.63 + 0. I, -2672.91 + 0. I, -1532.35 + 
  0. I, -690.738 + 0. I, -174.198 + 0. I, -1.45519*10^-11, -174.198 + 
  0. I, -690.738 + 0. I, -1532.35 + 0. I, -2672.91 + 0. I, -4080.63 + 
  0. I, -5721.25 + 0. I, -7560.71 + 0. I, -9566.98 + 0. I, -11711.1 + 
  0. I, -13967.8 + 0. I} *)
```

Using arbitrary-precision avoids the artifact

```
-Y[#, β] & /@ N[Range[-Xd0, Xd0, Xd0/10], 8] // FullSimplify

(* {-13967.839, -11711.129, -9566.975, -7560.713, -5721.254, -4080.6264, \
-2672.9051, -1532.3469, -690.7384, -174.19799, 0, -174.19799, -690.7384, \
-1532.3469, -2672.9051, -4080.6264, -5721.254, -7560.713, -9566.975, \
-11711.129, -13967.839} *)
```

The rest of your code has undefined terms.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I updated my question. In fact, I want to use `Y` in a piecewise function, and then matrix the piecewise function `Y` and matrix plot it, but It reminds me that `Less::nord: tried to use 37344.8-3240.47i for an invalid comparison`. I don't know why it happened but it looks like `MatrixPlot` the right thing.